# jQuery selector all the elements on parent level

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have to access all the elements at parent level.
  table
   tr
    td id="id"
   tr
   tr
   table

Here based on td id I have to select all the rows and hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply do

```
$("#tableID tr")
```

it will select all the immediate `tr` of the table with id `tableID`, moreover you can also select all the tr and examine the `id`

```
$("#tableID tr td").filter(return $(this).attr('id')!='idOfYourChoice').hide();
```

it will hide all the `td` except with the `id='idOfYourChoice'`